# Generating function for product of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

In general, if $a(n)$ is an integer sequence with generating function $A(t)$ and $b(n)$ is an integer sequence with generating function $B(t)$, it is not easy to find the generating function $C(t)$ for $c(n)=a(n)b(n)$ in terms of $A$ and $B$, i.e., to find the [Hadamard product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66130/generating-function-of-a-n2-in-terms-of-gf-of-a-n) of $A$ and $B$. However, it is not impossible to do so in some special cases.

I am interested in the case where $a(n) = \binom{N}{n}$ and $b(n) = \binom{M}{n}$, i.e., where the sequences are binomial coefficients. In this case $A(t) = (1+t)^N$ and $B(t) = (1+t)^M$. But what is $C$?

Thanks in advance for any advice or references!

Comment: [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+binom+%28N%2Cn%29+binom+%28M%2Cn%29+x^n+for+n%3D0..infinity) gives $_2F_1(-M,-N,;1;x)$; I suspect that if there were a way to express that more elementarily W|A would know about it.

Comment: Hmm ... thanks, that does seem like a reasonable conclusion.

Comment: If your still interested: I believe I can answer this using section 1.4 of GouldBK.pdf by Sprugnoli.  It used to be available freely but now you have to go through https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267825068_Riordan_Array_Proofs_of_Identities_in_Gould%27s_Book  .  Although I  think "fair use" means I could send you a copy.    OTOH: I can just write out the solution in "Your Answer".  The method falls under "Riordan Array transformations" if you want to search.

Comment: @rrogers I am extremely interested. These polynomials have just come up in my research on random string comparison in a big and surprising way. Would you be able to share Sprugnoli's paper and any insights of yours? I would be happy to tell you more and to acknowledge your help.

Comment: Here is a temporary copy (and email), please download soon.   I will take it down shortly:https://www.dropbox.com/sh/p0kl17awlxx15on/AAB-Gsw-prWZO87Ey8EfgQ-ka?dl=0
  Let me know when you copy; through here.  Hopefully before the Hall monitors descend.

Comment: @AlexanderTiskin  Actually, the notation is a little confusing, I can generate post an "improved" version that I can "read" :)  And, of course, I forgot too  post the "@" in the previous message :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "solution" that might be useful; but it is not wholly satisfactory.
(as usual read carefully before using (sigh!))
We use the “Snake Oil Method” from Wilf's book “generatingfunctionology” (second edition) [Amazon](https://smile.amazon.com/Generatingfunctionology-Herbert-S-Wilf-dp-1483248577/dp/1483248577/ref=mt_other)
or free: [Free version](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/gfology2.pdf)
A good book in either form. Chapter 4, page 125 and following the example on 126.  We get:
$\left(\begin{array}{c}
N\\
n
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
M\\
n
\end{array}\right)= \left[t^{n}\right]\left[s^{N}\right]\frac{1}{1-s}\cdot\left(1+\frac{\left(t\cdot s\right)}{\left(1-s\right)}\right)^{M}$
Let
$F(N,M,n;t)=\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}\left(\begin{array}{c}
N\\
n
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
M\\
n
\end{array}\right)t^{n}$
We “dodge the bullet” and sum on an independent parameter N and variable s. In this case it's easy to undo afterwards.
$f(M,N;s,t)={\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}\left(\begin{array}{c}
i\\
n
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
M\\
n
\end{array}\right)t^{n}s^{i}={\displaystyle {\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}}}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
M\\
n
\end{array}\right)t^{n}\cdot{\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
i\\
n
\end{array}\right)s^{i}$
$={\displaystyle {\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
M\\
n
\end{array}\right)\cdot t^{n}\cdot\frac{s^{n}}{\left(1-s\right)^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{1-s}\cdot{\displaystyle {\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
M\\
n
\end{array}\right)\cdot\frac{\left(t\cdot s\right)^{n}}{\left(1-s\right)^{n}}=\frac{1}{1-s}\cdot\left(1+\frac{\left(t\cdot s\right)}{\left(1-s\right)}\right)^{M}$
Now it's obvious how to pick out $t^{n}$
$\left[t^{n}\right]\frac{1}{1-s}\cdot\left(1+\frac{\left(t\cdot s\right)}{\left(1-s\right)}\right)^{M}=\frac{1}{1-s}\cdot\left(\begin{array}{c}
M\\
n
\end{array}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{\left(s\right)}{\left(1-s\right)}\right)^{n}$
And  $s^{N}$
$\left[s^{N}\right]\frac{1}{1-s}\left(\frac{\left(s\right)}{\left(1-s\right)}\right)^{n}=\left[s^{N-n}\right]\frac{1}{\left(1-s\right)^{n+1}}=\left(\begin{array}{c}
n+\left(N-n\right)\\
N-n
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
N\\
N-n
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
N\\
n
\end{array}\right)$
But not what we would prefer.
$\left[s^{N}\right]\frac{1}{1-s}\cdot\left(1+\frac{\left(t\cdot s\right)}{\left(1-s\right)}\right)^{M}$ to leave $\left[t^{n}\right]$

Which I can't see how to do.